# Cartoon about a young girl who travelled the country with a robot to find her father

Tags: story-identification, robots, cartoon

It is about a young girl, with short, blond hair, who travelled the country with a strong, yet kind, robot to find her father(?). All the while, they are being followed by an evil organisation.

In one episode they meet with Amish people and they are not allowed to use technology. The robot, Alex, who fortunately looks like a young man, was able to use his powers to save the leader's daughter's life from a flood, so they let them leave unharmed and thanked them.

Comment: Off to a good start, but we could use some more details, if you haven't already can I suggest you take a look at ["How to ask a good story-ID question?"](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and [edit] in any more details that checklist may help you remember!

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SpaceAmish

Comment: @Soso Ghally Either you, or the cartoon makers, should know that Amish people are allowed to used rather advanced technology - up to about the 19th century or so.  Also Amish people are officially pacifists, so letting visitors go unharmed should be expected of Amish people instead of being something unusual explained by plot developments.

Comment: If they were violently anti-tech, luddite might be a better way to describe them. Also, some Amish even use computers, cell phones etc.